# Issues controlling servo motors with serial monitor while using 16 channel servo Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, servo

I am making a 6-axis robotic arm that uses multiple servo motors.The goal is to create a program that accepts degree values from the serial monitor to control multiple servo motors.

I have just started programming with the Arduino, so I need help debugging a program that I have piece together from guides throughout the internet. The program will compile and upload, but when I input values into the serial monitor the servo will not move like I would like it to. At the moment, the servo motor will move 50 degrees. I have calibrated my servo but it still won't work properly. Furthermore, I kept the program for one servo just for testing I know that I will have to create an int motorA=0; motorB=1; etc. Any help will be appreciated

reference links:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=242458.0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8X9X10Tn1k

Hardware:
Arduino Uno 
16 channel Arduino Servo shield
5v external power supply 
MG995 Servo

Notes:
No connectivity issues 
Motor is connected properly
No hardware issues

Program:

```
enter code here
String readString;
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

#define SERVOMIN  650
#define SERVOMAX  2350
#define FREQUENCY 60

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

int motorA = 0;
int motorB = 1;

void setup() 
{ // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setPWMFreq(FREQUENCY);
}

void moveMotor(int ang, int motorOut)
{

 int angle = map(ang,0, 180, SERVOMIN,SERVOMAX);
 for ( uint16_t pulse_width = 0; pulse_width < angle; pulse_width++)
 {
   pwm.setPWM(motorOut, 0, pulse_width);

 }
}


void loop()
{
 //expect single strings like 30c, or 90a, or 180d,
//or combined like 30c,180b,70a,120d,

if (Serial.available())  
{
  char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
  if (c == ',') 
  {
    if (readString.length() >1)
    {
     Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out

     int angle = readString.toInt();  //convert readString into a number

     Serial.print("writing Angle: ");
     Serial.println(angle);
     if (readString.indexOf('a') >0) moveMotor(angle, motorA);

     readString=""; //clears variable for new input
   }
 }  
else {     
  readString += c; //makes the string readString
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you sending over serial to control the motor?

Comment: Degree values like 110a, or 120a, . The a just means motorA  and the number means the degree value

Comment: I don't see an obvious error. You can do some things, to further narrow down the problem: 1. Remove the for loop from `moveMotor()`, since it is too fast for the motor anyway, or make it slower by putting in a delay. 2. Check, if a PWM signal is actually outputted from the shield. If you don't have an oscilloscope, you can connect an LED to the channel and driving the channel slowly from 0% to 100% duty cycle (be sure to include a delay there). If the LED is fading in, the PWM signal is correctly outputed. 3. Recheck the pulse width, that your motors is reacting to and be sure to use it.

Comment: That clears up a lot thank you. I will use your advice. If I remove the for loop the motor will not move at all